# Incremental Performance Advantages to Defining Variables Outside of a Loop

Tags: node.js

I see a few answered questions on this topic related to C++ among other languages, but I couldn't readily find anything for Javascript, specifically Node JS.

Has anyone already benchmarked or is otherwise aware of any incremental performance advantages to declaring variables outside of a loop, versus inside, when the variables are intended to be re-initialized over and over inside the loop.

Outside of the loop:

```
let lis_id;
await std.asyncForEach(lis_recs, async lis_rec => {
  lis_id = lis_rec.LIS_ID;
});
```

Inside of the loop:

```
await std.asyncForEach(lis_recs, async lis_rec => {
  let lis_id = lis_rec.LIS_ID;
});
```

Clearly it's cleaner code to declare inside of the loop at time of initialization and re-initialization but is it less performant?